# JPG to PDF Conversion, How to Fit Full Page

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, imagemagick

I have page scans of various sizes in JPG format which I convert to a single PDF using ImageMagick. However I noticed every PDF page for each type of scan produces a different size PDF page, even if I use -page A4 option on ImageMagick. I would every JPG, in whatever size to "fill" each PDF page, and every PDF page to be the same. I also have access to tools like pdftk, pdfjam.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I used  -density 50% on ImageMagick convert it managed to zoom lower res images to bigger PDF pages.

Answer (score 4):

As a hack you can use **pdflatex** and the [wallpaper package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/wallpaper). It does the trick and has the advantage over most other methods of not altering the image content (resolution, compression, pixel content) and adds only about 1.2kB of overhead.

To keep the aspect ratio, use:

```
filename=test.jpg;
echo "\documentclass[a4paper]{article}\
\usepackage{wallpaper}\usepackage{grffile}\
\begin{document}\
\thispagestyle{empty}\
\ThisCenterWallPaper{1}{$filename}~\
\end{document}"\
| pdflatex --jobname "$filename";
rm "$filename".aux "$filename".log
```

To fill the page completely, use:

```
filename=test.jpg;
echo "\documentclass[a4paper]{article}\
\usepackage{wallpaper}\usepackage{grffile}\
\begin{document}\
\thispagestyle{empty}\
\ThisTileWallPaper{\paperwidth}{\paperheight}{$filename}~\
\end{document}"\
| pdflatex --jobname "$filename";
rm "$filename".aux "$filename".log
```

Finally you can concatenate your pages using [pdftk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/)

```
pdftk page1.pdf ... page2.pdf cat out final_document.pdf
```

Comment: After reading lots of posts on this subject and fighting with imagemagick into despair, and even obtaining an almost working solution, I find that this is the simplest, nicest solution, with no drawback whatsoever. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick, assuming your PDF output should have A4 sized pages (portrait):

```
convert  -scale 595x842\!  *.jpg  output.pdf
```

Comment: One can also use `-density` before output to get higher resolution versions, if needed. You also need to adjust the `-scale` option on match. Default resolution (dpi) is pretty poor.